# Limit drag-selection to a single row in QTableWidget

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I am using `QTableWidget` for my custom timeline view. I would like to limit the drag selection while preserving some properties of selection behavior and mode in a table widget.

Here is a small snippet of my code:

```
//TableWidget.cpp

TableWidget::TableWidget(QWidget* parent) : QTableWidget(10, 10, parent)
{
    setStyleSheet("QTableWidget {background-color: #333333;color: #fffff8;gridline-color: #fffff8;font-size: 12pt;}");

    verticalHeader()->hide();

    horizontalHeader()->setHighlightSections(false);

    setSortingEnabled(true);

    setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);

    setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
    setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows); 
}
```

**Problem**

As per [Qt-Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html) i could set `selectionBehavior` to `SelectRows` but it selects the complete Row with just one click on a cell. Problem is shown here:

[image]

**Requirement**

- Multiple selection by dragging the mouse but only in the row, it was first clicked.
- Dragging the mouse downward or diagonally should **NOT** select the multiple rows and columns as shown in the picture
  [image]
- *Shift Key*  property needs to be preserved i.e. clicking on a cell and then selecting another cell holding the shift key should select all the cells in-between.
- Multiple selection: I want to select multiple cells just by clicking on them without losing selection to the previous cells. `MultiSelection` as `selectionMode` provides this feature but it doesn't support *Shift Key*.

I tried to implement custom features using `mouseEvents` but i couldn't get how do i select/deselect a particular cell in `QTableWidget` programmatically. I believe i have to implement own `mouseEvents` but not sure how can i achieve the above mentioned features.

**Edit:** The `TableWidget` will always stay empty(no data to populate) as i am using the selection as visual presentation.

Comment: Use [model-view](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html) instead of widgets

Comment: I have edited the question. Does `QTableView` offer additional features keeping in mind i won't be using the table for any kind of data?

Comment: Usually no, additional features are implemented in model + delegates, not in view.